# getting 'Bad Request' while consuming json webservice using httpclient C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am getting bad StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request' with the below code.

```
string url = "http://1.1.1.1";
Object cu = new Object ();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cu);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cu), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api", content); //changed content from cu
var status = response.Result;
```

I noticed my status code's Content-Type: is still text/html instead of application/json.

Please assist.

Note: edited code above mentioned in comments. 
Also I am able to consume service by the below jquery. But I need the C# code to work.

```
    $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         type: "POST",
         async: true,
         url: RequestUrl,
         data: JSON.stringify(jData),
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (result) {
             alert(result.ResultCode);
         },
         error: function (result) {
             alert('error' + result.responseText);
         }
     });
```

Comment: I can't find a method named `PostAsJsonAsync` in `HttpClient`. What is this?

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov - see [HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasjsonasync%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Not really helpful without knowing what `jData` contains and what you're actually sending in the .NET code. You haven't provided a reproducible example which makes it very difficult to provide any kind of assistance other than wild guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it actually sets correct headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

So there is probably something wrong with your JSON. You should read documentation for your endpoint. It is also very helpful to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (great HTTP client) in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did download Fiddler and played around with it a little bit. However, even on Fiddler i noticed the content-type is text/html. 
How were you able to see json. Just curious.

Comment: Are you sure this content type is not from response?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're conforming to what the API expects? The JSON payload that you're sending is:

```
{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/json; charset=utf-8"]}]}
```

That seems a little odd to send as the payload.

I'm guessing that you're simply not conforming to the API. It probably expects you to send in either nothing or a very specifically formatted JSON object and you're not sending what it wants. As a result it's responding with "Bad Request" because the request is bad (i.e. not formatted correctly). Check the documentation for the API you're calling and ensure you're passing what it expects.

Are you sure the service needs to respond to a POST and not a GET?

Comment: I have a populated object that I am sending through C# code. just didnt add that in the snippet.  however i am pretty sure that object is correct since i am able to consume the service by jquery.

Comment: Then you need to compare the payload the jQuery is sending to the payload the .NET code is sending. Something is obviously different and I'd be willing to bet that the difference is in what you're sending. Without knowing what API you're calling (public, private) it's going to be impossible to diagnose what the problem actually is.